# Trying to understand this lua snippet

Tags: lua

I am trying to understand what this function does. Can anyone explain this to me?

```
function newInstance (class)
    local o = {}
    setmetatable (o, class)
    class.__index = class
    return o
end
```

It is called like this:

```
self = newInstance (self)
```

Comment: Please someone give a better title to this question cause I think it will help some developers out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This function apparently serves to provide a variant of OOP in Lua (a bit sloppy in my opinion).

This is a factory for a class.

It may be rewritten as follows, for clarity:

```
C = { }

C.foo = function(self) -- just some method, so class would not be empty
  print("foo method called", tostring(self))
end

C.__index = C -- (A)

function newInstance(class)
  return setmetatable({ }, class) -- (B)
end
```

Now if we create two new instances of C, we clearly see that both have a method foo(), but different self:

```
o1 = newInstance(C)
o1:foo() --> foo method called  table: 0x7fb3ea408ce0

o2 = newInstance(C)
o2:foo() --> foo method called  table: 0x7fb3ea4072f0
```

The foo methods are the same:

```
print(o1.foo, o2.foo, o1.foo == o2.foo and "equal" or "different")
--> function: 0x7fb3ea410760    function: 0x7fb3ea410760    equal
```

This is because table C (the "class") is an `__index` (`(A)` above) of metatable of `o1` and `o2`, set in `(B)`. But `o1` and `o2` are actually two different tables, created at `(B)` (the "class instances" or "objects").

Note: we set `C.__index` to be equal to `C` itself at `(A)` so we would reuse one table. Following has the same effect:

```
prototype = { }

prototype.foo = function(self) -- just some method, so class would not be empty
  print("foo method called", tostring(self))
end

C = { __index = prototype }

function newInstance(class)
  return setmetatable({ }, class)
end

o = newInstance(C)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is used to achieve object-oriented behavior in Lua. Lua uses prototype-based inheritance (similar to Javascript) instead of class-based inheritance (like Java or C++).
The idea is that all class methods are implemented as part of a prototype object and inheriting objects delegate to the prototype upon call.

For example, assume you want a class `myClass` providing a method `getMagicNumber`:

```
local myClass = { 
     getMagicNumber = function(self) 
         return self.theNumber;
     end };

local obj = newInstance(myClass);
obj.theNumber = 42;
print(obj:getMagicNumber()); -- supposed to return 42
```

It's kind of a trivial example, but I hope you get the idea. What happens is this: newInstance creates a new table with its metatable pointing to `myClass` and also ensuring that the `__index` field of the metatable points to myClass as well.
As the Lua manual on [`__index`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#2.4) describes, when you now attempt to call getMagicNumber on that new table, the following happens: First Lua attempts to find the field `getMagicNumber` in the `obj` table. Since that table is empty though, it now searches its `__index` table (`myClass`) for that field. Since the field is found there, it now calls the function found in `myClass`.

[Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) discusses this mechanism in great detail if you need to know more.

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone it took me a fair bit of time to grok this code. Here's my interpretation

each table can have a netatable, the metatable can store amongst other things functions indexed by name, and setmetatable sets the value of the metatable naturally enough.

The line class._index = .. is where the magic happens.

When you try to call a function using self.fn1(), Then lua looks up in the self a name fn1. If it can't find it then it looks in self's metatable for a table `__index`, and looks for a 'fn1' in the table stored there.

Now the metatable for self in your example is class, so lua looks for an __index entry in the metatable (class) to see if there's a function named fn1 in that table, and there is, so it's returned. You need to set the __index for class back to itself so that lua will look in the same metatable - confusing hey.

(as an aside the assignment to __index only needs to happen once, but for some reason it's always done in the new operator in all the lua examples - I take it outside of the new in my classes - saves a few cycles)

You then return the new table o, lua is garbage collected so returning a local creates a new table each time.

```
function newInstance (class)
    local o = {}
    setmetatable (o, class)
    class.__index = class
    return o
end
```

hth